Problem using purrr to map a list of variables into a function
I am working with the unvotes package, the objective is "Using purrr functionality, find out which three countries on average agreed with the US the most from the year 2000 on". I first created this function below to calculate agreement rates between any two countries from year x on:
votes_agreement_calculator <- function(country_code1, country_code2, year_min) {
library(unvotes)
data("un_votes")
data("un_roll_calls")
un_votes2 <-  un_votes %>%
  inner_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid")
un_votes2$year <- format(un_votes2$date, "%Y")
subset <- un_votes2 %>% 
  dplyr::select(year, unres, country_code, vote) %>% 
  filter(country_code == country_code1 | country_code == country_code2,
                year >= year_min) %>%
  group_by(unres) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = country_code,
              values_from = vote,
              values_fn = first) %>% 
filter(!is.na(!!sym(country_code1)) & !is.na(!!sym(country_code2))) %>% 
  #!!sym() so that R recognizes the inputs as columns 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(total = n(),
              agree = sum(!!sym(country_code1) == !!sym(country_code2), na.rm = TRUE),  
              share = agree / total) 
return(mean(subset$share, na.rm = TRUE))
}

I first ran into some problems because in filter() and sum() it wouldn't recognise my inputs as columns, and ChaGPT suggested putting !!sym() so that columns are recognized. Thne I tested the function above and it works fine. I then created created a new function so that it only takes one country as an argument:
new_function <- function(country_code) {votes_agreement_calculator(country_code, "US", 2000)
}

#checking if the results are the same as before
new_function("RU") #yes they are 

This function also works fine, then I used dplyr to group the data by the country code and pass the column of the countries codes into the function using purrr
#passing list of country codes as a vector into the new function 
votes_US_agreement <- un_votes2 %>%
  group_by(country_code) %>% 
  mutate(agreement_rate = purrr::map_vec(country_code, new_function)) %>%
  arrange(desc(agreement_rate)) %>% #arrange them in in descending order 
  slice_head(n = 3) #check the first three with the most agreement rates out 

But then R just wouldn't give me an output and just keeps running the above code for hours on end, without an error message or anything like that.
Would really appreciate if someone gives me a pointed as to what's wrong with my code :)
I expected the mapping a list of variables into the function should work fine because giving the function individual arguments worked without a problem, but it didn.t...instead it keeps running without stop...

I identified three issues in the code you posted.

You are loading the unvotes package and its data at the top of the function. This should be done outside of the function so this code
only gets executed once. Also some of the data transformation you are doing within the function has the same results for whatever values
you use as arguments. These steps should also be done outside of the function.
ChatGPT provided you a working but deprecated solution to use characters at variable strings in dplyr verbs that use data masking.
Instead of !!sym(x) it is
recommended to use .data[[x]]. Read Programming with dplyr to learn more. Note that this type of
behavior is specific to dplyr and the tidyverse and not a general/base-R thing.
When you are iterating over the country_code column in the un_votes2 data frame, you are repeating the same calculation for a country every time it occurs in un_votes2.
Instead you’d want to only do it once per each country. Also your choice of transformation steps in the function is not best for performance. In
my experience dplyr::*_join() operations perform much better for this type of comparison tasks than tidyr::pivot_wider(). If we re-think
the function with join operations we can implement a function that instead of running the
function for each combination of countries, you can run it once for each country (i.e. “US”) and let it produce the comparison to all other countries.

Below is an example that solves the issues I found. Please make sure to review the calculations and ensure that they are doing
what you are expecting.
# Packages and data are loaded outside of function.
library(unvotes)
library(tidyverse)
data("un_votes")
data("un_roll_calls")

# Data transformations that are necessary for all further steps are done outside of the function.
un_votes2 <-
  un_votes %>%
  inner_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid") %>%
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
  dplyr::select(year, unres, country_code, vote)


# The function takes only one country code as input and then returns the agreement share with all other countries in the specified time frame.
votes_agreement_calculator <- function(country_code1, year_min) {
  target_subset <-
    un_votes2 %>%
    filter(
      country_code == country_code1,
      year >= year_min,
      !is.na(country_code)
    )

  non_target_subset <-
    un_votes2 %>%
    filter(
      country_code != country_code1,
      year >= year_min,
      !is.na(country_code)
    )

  left_join(
    non_target_subset,
    target_subset,
    by = c("year", "unres"),
    relationship = "many-to-many"
  ) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    mutate(agree = vote.x == vote.y) %>%
    group_by(country_code.x) %>%
    summarise(agree_share = sum(agree, na.rm = TRUE) / n())
}

We can now run the function for one country at a time. To answer your research question we use "US" and sort descending by the agreement share.
votes_agreement_calculator(
  country_code1 = "US",
  year_min = 2000
) %>%
  arrange(desc(agree_share))
#> # A tibble: 192 × 2
#>    country_code.x agree_share
#>    <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1 IL                   0.772
#>  2 FM                   0.688
#>  3 PW                   0.641
#>  4 MH                   0.617
#>  5 CA                   0.521
#>  6 GB                   0.492
#>  7 AU                   0.452
#>  8 FR                   0.448
#>  9 MC                   0.401
#> 10 CZ                   0.401
#> # ℹ 182 more rows

Or all countries:
un_votes %>%
  pull(country_code) %>%
  # we are using `unique()` to make sure that each country code is used only once
  unique() %>%
  # `set_names()` applies the country code values as names to itself, this is useful for map
  # to produce named results and `list_rbind()` being able to identify the target country.
  set_names() %>%
  map(votes_agreement_calculator, year_min = 2000) %>%
  list_rbind(names_to = "target_country")
#> # A tibble: 37,828 × 3
#>    target_country country_code.x agree_share
#>    <chr>          <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1 US             AD                   0.354
#>  2 US             AE                   0.148
#>  3 US             AF                   0.169
#>  4 US             AG                   0.168
#>  5 US             AL                   0.394
#>  6 US             AM                   0.197
#>  7 US             AO                   0.148
#>  8 US             AR                   0.224
#>  9 US             AT                   0.346
#> 10 US             AU                   0.452
#> # ℹ 37,818 more rows


Thank you so much for your help!! I used  .data[[x]] instead of  !!sym(x)and it went perfectly. I still wanted to make my original code work so instead of putting everything in a dplyr chain, i created a list of country codes as a vector and then passed it to the function and it finally worked. However, the results are a bit different than yours from using left_join() , I wonder why that is

Update:
found out the main problem with purrr:map() was that dplyr created a data frame and not a vector, which doesn't work when passing through commands like filter() in the function. So I adjusted my code based on @Till 's suggestion. I first took some steps and put it outside of the function, then used  .data[[x]] instead of  !!sym(x) in the function, then created a list of country codes as vector to pass into function with purrr:map(). Here's the updated solution:
library(unvotes)
data("un_votes")
data("un_roll_calls")
un_votes2 <-
  un_votes %>%
  inner_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
  select(year, unres, country_code, vote)

#adjusting the code to avoid !!sym() easier for mapping 
votes_agreement_calculator2 <- function(country_code1, country_code2, year_min) {
subset <- un_votes2 %>% 
  filter(country_code == country_code1 | country_code == country_code2,
                year >= year_min) %>%
  group_by(unres) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = country_code,
              values_from = vote,
              values_fn = first) %>% 
 filter(!is.na(.data[[country_code1]]) & !is.na(.data[[country_code2]])) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(total = n(),
              agree = sum(.data[[country_code1]] == .data[[country_code2]], na.rm = TRUE),  
              share = agree / total)
  return(mean(subset$share, na.rm = TRUE))
}

votes_agreement_calculator2("US", "RU", 2000)

#creating new function so that it only needs one agreement 
new_function <- function(country_code) {votes_agreement_calculator2(country_code, "US", 2000)
}

#checking if the results are the same as before
new_function("RU") #yes they are 
#creating a list of countries minus the US as a vector 
country_codes_no_US <- un_votes2 %>% 
  filter(country_code != "US",
         year >= 2000) %>%
  distinct(country_code) %>% 
  pull(country_code) 
  
#passing the vector list into the new function 
agreement_rate <- map_dbl(country_codes_no_US, new_function)
#putting countries and agreement rates into a data frame 
 votes_US_agreement <- 
   tibble(country_code = country_codes_no_US, #putting 
          agreement_rate = agreement_rate) %>% 
  arrange(desc(agreement_rate)) %>% #arrange them in in descending order 
  print(slice_head(n = 3)) #check the first three with the most agreement rates out 

